# How to save a statically optional value

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Consider a function which wraps some other function but does something after the wrapped call.

```
template< typename ftor, typename ... args >
typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type
call_and_report( ftor && f, args && ... a ) {
    auto && ret{ f( std::forward< args >( a ) ... ) };
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
    return std::forward< typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type >
                       ( ret );
}
```

How to extend this to wrap functions that return `void`? It's easy to add another specialization, but I'm looking for another way that could be idiomatic.

The general idea is that there may or may not be a value. It's like compile-time `optional`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, never mind :-S

Answer (score 4):

It is legal to return with the execution of your function:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto call_and_report(F && f, Args && ... a) 
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(a)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
}
```

Now to do something after your call, you could do it at the destructor of an object:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto call_and_report(F && f, Args && ... a) 
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(a)...))
{
    struct execute { ~execute() { std::cout << "Done!" << '\n'; } } execute;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. Can it be better? Say if I want to print some params? then we've to pass them to the constructor, which makes it less interesting.

Comment: Well, that's something. Actually I specifically don't want it to execute if there was an exception, though. There is `std::uncaught_exception` which comes oh so close to making such a thing work…

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've been playing around some, but I still think `enable_if` might be more appropriate in this case - I see no easy way to simulate the same behavior in case of exceptions. But maybe someone else has more success with it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to execute the additional code in a destructor of a local object. Doing so allows to directly pass the result through, too, which can elide the copy/move otherwise required fir non-lvalue returns:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
...
call_and_forward(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    struct report {
        ~report() { std::cout << "done\n"; }
    } reporter;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as the other answer. I believe it's impossible to make this behave similarly to the original when exiting due to an exception, in the case it is executed from a stack unwind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at moving the problem to a dedicated wrapper in such a form that it can at least be reused.

Not sure of correctness, haven't even tried to compile it once. At the least, the `static_cast` makes an unnecessary copy when returning by value.

I'm just doing this of curiosity, don't actually need a solution to this problem, but it looks fairly onerous.

```
template< typename ftor, typename ... args >
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_void< typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type >::value,
    typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type >::type
call_or_wrap_void( ftor && f, args && ... a )
    { return std::forward< ftor >( f ) ( std::forward< args >( a ) ... ); }

struct void_wrapper {};

template< typename ftor, typename ... args >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_void< typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type >::value,
    void_wrapper >::type
call_or_wrap_void( ftor && f, args && ... a ) {
    std::forward< ftor >( f ) ( std::forward< args >( a ) ... );
    return {};
}

template< typename ftor, typename ... args >
typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type
call_and_report( ftor && f, args && ... a ) {
    auto && ret{ call_or_wrap_void( std::forward< ftor >( f ), std::forward< args >( a ) ... ) };
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
    return static_cast< typename std::result_of< ftor( args ... ) >::type >
                      ( std::move( ret ) );
}
```